# References to cstheory in the literature

Tags: discussion

This is a placeholder question to collect instances where cstheory has been cited in papers. Hopefully as time goes in, this list will get longer.

Please answer in the format:

> - Question (and answer, if appropriate)
> - Cited in:

providing all links and citations necessary.

Comment: Curious why this was in meta rather than the main site? In particular, I'm wondering about how many papers/results had their *genesis* here, and I worry that posting such a question on meta would result in not much visibility. And while several of the answers here may fit the bill (eg mine - but I can't be the only one!), it's harder to offload to Google scholar.

Comment: Maybe the tag ([meta-tag:citations]) would fit here? (I do not have sufficient rep to edit on meta, so I have suggested this in a comment.)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of curating a list here (how current is this list, anyway?) we can happily delegate the work to the keeper of all data:

[References to cstheory.SE on Google Scholar](http://goo.gl/3mUWt)

Comment: nice. we were updating the list manually, but this seems to work as well.

Answer (score 7):

**Question**: [How hard is unshuffling a string?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-hard-is-unshuffling-a-string)

**Cited in**:

- Dane Henshall, Narad Rampersad, and Jeffrey Shallit. [Shuffling and Unshuffling](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5767).  ArXiv:1106.5767v4.
- Sam Buss and Michael Soltys. [Unshuffling a square is NP-hard](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.7161).  ArXiv:1211.7161.

Answer (score 6):

**Question**: [Is optimally solving the n×n×n Rubik's Cube NP-hard?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/783/is-optimally-solving-the-nnn-rubiks-cube-np-hard)

**Cited in**: [Algorithms for Solving Rubik's Cubes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5736). Erik D. Demaine, Martin L. Demaine, Sarah Eisenstat, Anna Lubiw, Andrew Winslow. arXiv:1106.5736v1

(Also pointed out in the question's answer by @Andy Drucker.)

Answer (score 6):

**Question:** [Post Correspondence Problem variant](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/post-correspondence-problem-variant)

**Cited in:** Levent Alpoge, Thomas Ang, Luke Schaeffer, Jeffrey Shallit (2011): Decidability and shortest strings in formal languages, *Proc. DCFS 2011*, LNCS vol. 6808, Springer. [doi:10.1007/978-3-642-22600-7_5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-22600-7_5), [arXiv:1103.1622](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1622)

Answer (score 2):

**Question**: [Why is HAMILTONIAN CYCLE so different from PERMANENT?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/27496/129)

**Cited in**: Grochow, J. A. [Monotone Projection Lower Bounds from Extended Formulation Lower Bounds.](http://dx.doi.org/10.4086/toc.2017.v013a018) Theory of Computing Vol. 13 Art. 18, 2017.