# A decade of CSTheory

Tags: discussion

I believe August 16, 2020 is the 10th anniversary of CSTheory, also known as TCS.se.

What are some Questions and Answers (and Comments?) that you remember fondly, or want to bring attention back to, from the decade that was?

Comment: This might also be good for the decade of celebration: https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/references-to-cstheory-in-the-literature

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My favorite is [How hard is unshuffling a string](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-hard-is-unshuffling-a-string)?

It is attractive because it is very simple to state yet has many equivalent formulations. It illustrates a puzzling feature of perfect matching problem (efficiently solvable) where imposing some restrictions turns the problem into an intractable one.

Comment: Didn't know about that one but now I think it's my favorite too.